# Controlling a servo at Raspberry Pi with Springboot and ServoBlaster

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, raspberry-pi3, servo, pi4j

I am trying to control a servo motor from a web interface. I am using [SpringBoot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) 2.0, [ServoBlaster](https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/tree/master/ServoBlaster) and [pi4j](https://pi4j.com/1.2/index.html).

In order to start the application I am running as root `./gradlew bootrun --no-daemon`. It has to be root in order to handle the GPIOs and I don't have any security worries about the device.

In simplified (a class with just the `main` function) Java/Kotlin I achieved to control the servo by any of the following ways:

1. RPIServoBlasterProvider

   `val servoProvider = RPIServoBlasterProvider()
    val servo0 = servoProvider.getServoDriver(servoProvider.definedServoPins[5])
    println("Go to 150") //middle
    servo0.servoPulseWidth = 150
    println("Went to ${servo0.servoPulseWidth}")
    Thread.sleep(1550)`
2. Write to `/dev/servoblaster`

   `val out = PrintWriter(FileOutputStream("/dev/servoblaster"), true)
    println("Go to 65 again")
    out.println("5=65")
    out.flush()
    out.close`
3. Call a secondary script which writes to `/dev/servoblaster`

   `val servoId = 5
    val script = "/home/pi/ServoHardwareSteering.sh"
    val cmdMinPosition = "$script $servoId 65"
    val cmdMidPosition = "$script $servoId 150"
    val cmdMaxPosition = "$script $servoId 235"
    val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
    println(cmdMidPosition)
    runtime.exec(cmdMidPosition)//.waitFor()
    Thread.sleep(1550)`
4. Write the value to a file and have a secondary execute reading this file and applying this value to the servo

I have tried all of the above in `Springboot` but without success.

So the question is, could somebody tell me how could I:

1. use the `RPIServoBlasterProvider` class from `Springboot`? **OR**
2. write to `/dev/servoblaster`? **OR**
3. execute any terminal script? **OR**
4. where to save the script in order to be able to call it **OR**
5. *write to a simple file (ex. afile.txt)?* **OR**
6. solve the issue in a better way that I did not think about already.

Solutions at any of the above questions could help me solve my problem.

*PS: Is there anything wrong with the blockquote for the source code in stackoverflow? I could not format it as a block and I used the line code formatting!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem was with the `servod` of the `ServoBlaster`. It was accidentally killed and I had to run it once again!
I followed the **No 5** solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
use the RPIServoBlasterProvider class from Springboot? OR
```

The same you did before - its Java (kotlin is based on) - or just use Kotlin with Spring https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/

```
write to /dev/servoblaster? OR
```

The same like  you did - everything is a file in linux, thus its writing to a ordinary file

```
execute any terminal script? OR
```

`Runtime.getRuntime.exec` - any variant or `ProcessBuilder`

```
where to save the script in order to be able to call it OR
```

Anywhere

```
write to a simple file (ex. afile.txt)? OR
```

point 2.

```
solve the issue in a better way that I did not think about already.
```

No experience with servo blaster.

Comment: I already have said that `I have tried all of the above in Springboot but without success.`. I would a prefer an answer containing source code or link to examples.

Comment: You obviously did it wrong and you haven't include any meaningfull code + nobody knows whats wrong with it. That's the best you can get now.

Comment: I am going to try it once again and I will come back with more info.